# Salesforce Amazon S3 Integration

Tags: integration, amazon

Is there any API call supported by Amazon to upload a file to multiple folders at one go?

I have one bucket called 'TEST' and within that bucket I have multiple folders '1000', '2222', so I need to upload the file to both the folders.

Any thoughts?

Thanks
/Roshan

Comment: I think you have more chance of getting solution for this question on stackoverflow than stackexchange salesforce.Amazon community may help as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, all of the S3 API operations only apply to a single object/bucket/key. Therefore, to upload to multiple "folders" you will need to do multiple operations. S3 does support a "copy object" operation that will be much more efficient for your second call.

Salesforce supports up to 10 outbound web service callouts per request, so this approach should work fine unless you are trying to upload to more than 10 keys in a single request.